# two service calls happening at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- i am new to react..
- i have two service calls happening at the same time...
- from both the services i need to retrive date and display it separately..
- right now I retrieve date from one service and display at both the places..
- can you guys tell me how to retrieve the date from another service too...
- i have components folder... inside components folder there is another folder called accoun...inside sports folder there is two different folders info and snapshot folder....each of this folder contain separate file
- in one service call I am getting the answers at this location, need to display this answers at another file

  ```javascript

  - one file code

  const {answers} = this.props;
  console.log("this.props=== sports-snapshot-presenter----->" + JSON.stringify(this.props));

  - another file code given below

  Your Total Return
          
              {
                  answers.essay.error || answers.essay.light === undefined ||
                  answers.essay.light === null || answers.essay.light.length === 0 ? null :
                  `(As of ${moment(answers.essay.light, SportsPICTURE.INPUT_PEN_FORMAT)
                      .format(SportsPICTURE.OUTPUT_PEN_FORMAT)})`
              }

  {
          answers.inception.error || isNaN(answers.inception.percentage) ?
              **Unavailable** :
              
                  {`${this.addSignForNumeral(answers.inception.percentage)}%`}
              
      }

  ```
  entire code in the gist below
  https://gist.github.com/texirv/7bf04112db4e75e5252168cc86eeacc2

Comment: Please format your code, it's a mass now.

Comment: @huachengzan i tried formatting...but there is some problem